# How to put a div on top of another div without using position absolute?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have 2 images which are centered with margins, I need to put them in the right way without using `position:absolute`, since if I do use it, on zoom in/out they will move right/left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
img

{
position:relative;
margin: 0 auto;
clear:both;
display: block;
}
```

Or:

```
.centerme {
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%; //or any other value
  text-align:center
}
```

Sample HTML:

```
<div class="centerme">
  <img src="#" height="200px" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="centerme">
  <img src="#" height="200px" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: And if one of the Div is a text?

Comment: then you need to either target divs, or better, add classes on divs and put images/text inside divs, that's the safest and the most correct way. will update my answer now.

Comment: That's exactly what I have done, still it is not working.

Comment: It is hard to know without seeing the code in action

Comment: @ValioRaltchev - If you can share your code then we can inspect and help you solving the issue.

Comment: Actually it worked ( It didn't display your edit at the first refresh) thank you!